# Passing dictionary to wtforms forms.py (*args, **kwargs) issues

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Creating a flask app and having an issue passing a dictionary from my views.py page to my form.py page.  The dictionary will be created dynamically based upon uploaded data.  For now it is hardcoded.  I have to pass to create a dynamic number of fields.

views.py

```
select_dict = {'Geography': ['US', 'Asia', 'Europe'], 'Product Type': ['X', 'Y', 'Z']}
form = F(request.form,select_dict)
```

form.py

```
class SimpleForm(Form):
    list_of_files = ['Option 1','Option 2','Option 3','Option 4','Option 5','Option 6']
    files = [(x, x) for x in list_of_files]
    acheckbox = MultiCheckboxField('Label',choices=files)
    third_list = ['Special Analysis']
    third_files = [(x, x) for x in third_list] 
    bcheckbox = MultiCheckboxField('Label', choices=third_files)
    category_1 = SelectField(u'', choices=())
    category_2 = SelectField(u'', choices=())
    category_3 = SelectField(u'', choices=())

class F(SimpleForm):
    pass

    def __init__(self, select_dict, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(select_dict)
        for name,choices in select_dict.items():
            test = [(x, x) for x in choices]
            setattr(F, name, SelectMultipleField(name.title(),choices=test))
```

The code works if I define select_dict in forms and only include the "for" loop.  Right now I keep getting this error: "formdata should be a multidict-type wrapper that supports the 'getlist' method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched the order of the arguments passed to the form. The correct way is below:

```
form = F(select_dict, request.form)
```